# Hive query regarding insert into

Tags: hive, hql

I have a table tableA and creating tableB as

```
 CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS db.tableB LIKE db.tableA;
```

Then inserting the data between date1 to date 7 using below command

```
insert overwrite table  db.tableB partition (yymmddval, yymmddcrt)
    select *
    from db.tableA
    where 1 = 1
      and yymmddval between '${start}' and '${end}' ; # date 1 to date 7
```

Now I want to insert new  data into my tableB from table A from date 11 to date 17 without losing date1 to date7 data.

```
insert into table  db.tableB partition (yymmddval, yymmddcrt)
    select *
    from db.tableA
    where 1 = 1
      and yymmddval between '${start}' and '${end}' ; # date 11 to date 17
```

So do I have to use partition syntax again in the second `insert into` command? I cannot run the two command in one shot

Comment: Sure you have to. Your insert sentence seems correct. What is wrong with it?

Comment: @leftjoin i want to is this partition (yymmddval, yymmddcrt) is  optional or not in case of second insert into statement

Comment: second or third does not matter. If table is partitioned, partition is mandatory